# css - circle with margin on border

Tags: css

I am trying to create a circle with an outline that has margin.
Everything seems to work except i cant seem to get that few `px` of margin in there.
Any suggestions please?

[image]

```
.ui-corner-all { -moz-border-radius: 30px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px; border-radius: 30px; border: 1px solid black; margin:5px; width:30px; height:30px;}
```

heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/K6pdr/

Comment: [You're approaching this the wrong way; that's not a margin, that's a border](http://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/bEpdL).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I'd say to treat it like this:

Outer "border" - use a [box shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)
Inner "margin" - use a white border
Inner area - use background color

All together you get:

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #F80;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #888;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

---

You can make the outer border more distinct by setting blur-radius to 0 on box-shadow.

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #F80;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 18px;

  /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #888;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

---

As an alternative, you could use a second element:

```css
.circle {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 19px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner {
  background-color: #F80;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 3px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The outer border is quite faint. Is there a way to make it a bit more visible? edit: needed an extra zero in there `box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff;`

Comment: @adamj added this to the answer

Comment: For high-dpi screens you can use .5 to represent a device pixel if the 1px is too thin and 2px is too thick. eg. `0px 0px 0px 1.5px red` - I'm not sure if 'standard' resolution screens will round this up or down.

Comment: This box-shadow saved me. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, only firefox supports this. Here is a work around that does the same thing, and even works with dashed outlines.

[image: circle]

```css
.has-outline {
    background: #51ab9f;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.has-outline:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed #9dd5cf;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  right: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="has-outline">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
.ui-corner-all { -moz-border-radius: 30px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px; border-radius: 30px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 2px; background: #fcc; width: 30px; height: 30px; }
```

Or with inner padding:

```
.ui-corner-all2 { -moz-border-radius: 30px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px; border-radius: 30px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px; background: #fcc;  width: 30px; height: 30px; }
```

See also on this fiddle the difference when using margin vs padding CSS properties.

**[http://jsfiddle.net/MQx7r/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/MQx7r/)**

Comment: i dont see a gap between the background and the stroke like the image in my post

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outline` in combination with `outline-radius`.
Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuRVX/).

Comment: Only firefox supports outline radius.